# URL Rewrting not working in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

i have to just test the url rewriting in my joomla 2.5 I have edited the .htaccess page by using a line as

```
RewriteRule  ^web/company/([A-za-z0-9-]+)$  index.php [NC,L]
```

I have also set the flag of "Use URL rewriting" as "Yes" in Global Configuration of Joomla.

Now, When I use a url as "http://localhost/joomla/web/company/about-us" then displays me `404 Not Found page`,

Can some one guide me what could be the solution for this?

- OS: Ubuntu 10.04
- PHP5+
- Joomla 2.5+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set URL rewriting to OFF in your backend and copy the "about-us" URL page (index.php?....).
In your .htaccess file, delete "index.php" and paste the new one.